# Why I cannot receive data from USB to arduino when I connect direct from TX and RX arduino to TX and RX USB (D+ and D-)

Tags: arduino

I just want to create a system which can scan barcode using barcode scanner(with USB) and send to arduino TX and RX pin. When i google about USB cable, I found USB cable also have TX and RX (D+ and D-). Why I cannot receive data from USB to arduino when I connect direct from TX and RX arduino to TX and RX USB (D+ and D-). I hope someone will tell me why? TQ

[image: MY CONNECTION]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is an USB-to-TTL-Serial adapter cable on the last photo. do you see the large connector body. there is an FTDI inside.

Comment: @Juraj What's wrong with FTDI sir?

Comment: that you don't have it in your setup with the cut USB cable

Answer (score 3):

USB TX/RX pins follow a totally different electrical specification to that of the UART TX/RX pins of the Arduino.

USB is a differential signal where as the UART of the arduino expects a 5v logic level.

Connecting both together risks damaging both devices.

You can buy USB host "shields" for Arduinos which would allow you to connect this USB device (theoretically)